# Is it possible to get the list of all Workitem Types in a Project collection?

Tags: c#, collections, tfs-sdk

I am trying to get the list of all the `workitem types` from `project collection` without accessing `project` in `project collection`.

**I have tried till now**

I can get the list of all `workitemType` list using `project` object as in following code:

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tfctc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(newUri
            ("http://servername:8080/tfs/teamprojectcollection"));
 WorkItemStore wis = tfctc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

 foreach(Project project in wis.Projects)
 {               
   foreach (WorkItemType type in project.WorkItemTypes)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
   }
 }
```

By searching on getting list of `WorkitemType` I come to know one class in TFS as [WorkItemTypeCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemTypeCollection.aspx).

but while using it I am not able to get the object of `workitemcollection` using `projectCollection`.

I have tried below code to do so:

```
 TfsTeamProjectCollection tfctc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(newUri
            ("http://servername:8080/tfs/teamprojectcollection"));
 WorkItemTypeCollection witc = tfctc.GetService<WorkItemTypeCollection>(); // here I am getting nil object every time
// some more code
```

**What I Want to do**

I want to get the list of **`WorkItemTypes`** in a `projectcollection`.

Can anyone help me on this?
Correct me if I am wrong any where.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Work Item Types are associated to team projects, so you can only get Work Item Types for Team Projects. The reason behind this is that each Team Project can have different sets of Work Item Types. And even if you find multiple types that are equally named, e.g. "Task" or "Bug", each Team Project may have modified its definition. So essentially, the combined Work Item Types of all of your Team Projects are the Work Item Types of your Team Project Collection.

The `WorkItemTypeCollection` class that you have found is actually a container for `WorkItemType` instances. The `Project.WorkItemTypes` property that you have already used returns a `WorkItemTypeCollection` that you can iterate. Though, this type is not registered as a service - that's why `tfctc.GetService<WorkItemTypeCollection>()` returns null.

So, what you have done in your nested `foreach` in the example is actually how it works. You can refine that using LINQ and `SelectMany`, but that's about it:

```
var workItemTypes = wis.Projects
                       .Cast<Project>()
                       .SelectMany(p => p.WorkItemTypes.Cast<WorkItemType>())
                       .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me the use of `WorkItemTypeCollection`?